# QueryDSL dynamic predicates

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I need help with QueryDSL querying. I'm using this library with Spring Data JPA.
My service class:

```
@Service("tblActivityService")
public class TblActivityService implements AbstractService<TblActivity> {

@Resource
private TblActivityRepository tblActivityRepository;

@Override
public List<TblActivity> findAll(Predicate predicate) {
    return (List<TblActivity>) tblActivityRepository.findAll(predicate);
}
}
```

I have dynamic list of filters:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sys_filters")
public class SysFilter implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "filter_id")
private Integer filterId;

@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private SysUser userId;

@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "table_name")
private String tableName;

@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "column_name")
private String columnName;

@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "condition")
private String condition;

@Size(max = 100)
@Column(name = "value")
private String value;


// getters & setters

}
```

I have column name (e.g. title)
I have condition (e.g. ==, !=, >= etc.) - I can store it as symbols or words (equals etc.)
And finally I have value.

The question is "how to dynamically generate predicate for my service?"
Table has about 25 fields.

Predicate looks like that:

```
public BooleanExpression buildFilteredResult(List<SysFilter> filters) {
    //TODO do it!
    return QTblActivity.tblActivity.title.eq("Value"); 
// I need to do it dynamically for each filter in the list
}
```

The problem is how to invoke columnName by its string value.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Providing column names as string values defeats the purpose of Querydsl.
The idea behind Querydsl is that you do NOT need the column names as strings but refer to them in a compile-safe and type-safe way.

Comment: Well, I don't want to write code for all possible variants (it would be a lot of code). Is there any way to insert column name dynamically? Or maybe some other way to implement my needs without QueryDSL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be easier to use a mapping filter conditions to operators

```
Map<String, Operator> operators = ImmutableMap.of(
  "==", Ops.EQ, "!=", Ops.NE, ">", Ops.GT, "<", Ops.LT,
  ">=", Ops.GOE, "<=", Ops.LOE);

Expressions.predicate(operators.get(condition), 
  stringPath, Expressions.constant(filterValue));
```

Also make sure you combine your predicates properly

```
predicates.and(...)
```

returns a new predicate and leaves `predicates` untouched.

Maybe `BooleanBuilder` is what you are after?

Comment: if the property is a NumberPath, how can do it?

Answer (score 1):

A newer solution was released with spring data Gosling/Fowler. If you are creating a web app, you can use the querydsl web support that does the work for you -it reads the get parameters into a predicate and then you can use this predicate from your controller - no need to manually do that - 
You can customize your repository based on the search criteria (equal, like ...) needed for a particular datatype or particular entity's field.
[see the documentation here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.type-safe)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
public BooleanExpression buildFilteredResult(List<SysFilter> filters) {
    //TODO do it!

    QTblActivity qTblActivity = QTblActivity.tblActivity;
    BooleanExpression expression = qTblActivity.recordState;

    for (SysFilter filter : filters) {
        StringPath stringPath = new StringPath(qTblActivity, filter.getColumnName());
        switch (filter.getCondition()) {
            case "==":
                expression.and(stringPath.eq(filter.getValue()));
                break;
            case "!=":
                expression.and(stringPath.ne(filter.getValue()));
                break;
            case ">":
                expression.and(stringPath.gt(filter.getValue()));
                break;
            case "<":
                expression.and(stringPath.lt(filter.getValue()));
                break;
            case ">=":
                expression.and(stringPath.goe(filter.getValue()));
                break;
            case "<=":
                expression.and(stringPath.loe(filter.getValue()));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    return expression;

}
```